# How to access the AudioContext from within an AudioWorkletProcessor?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, audio-worklet

When creating an AudioWorkletProcessor the context is provided:

`new AudioWorklet( audioContext, 'worklet-name', options )`.

Inside the worklet there doesn't seem to be any way to access that context. How do we access critical Audio functions like `createBuffer`?

Raw buffers (Float32Array) aren't sufficient because the audio buffer interface accepts the sample rate. Without the sample rate, the audio is played through at the wrong pitch.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to access the `AudioContext` itself from within an `AudioWorkletProcessor`.

But there are some globals which might come in handy:

- **`currentTime`**: This is the same value which can be accessed as a property with the same name of an `AudioContext` on the main thread.
- **`currentFrame`** This is the same value as `currentTime` but in frames.
- **`sampleRate`**: This is also the same value which can be accessed as a property with the same name of an `AudioContext` on the main thread.